# Docu Sign - how to click on multiple Sign here buttons inside a iframe

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a docu sign page inside an iframe, and on the page there are multiple 'Sign Here' buttons which are dynamic - one test case can have 2 another can have 3 signatures.

and the actual x-path has a dynamic id trailing the element id - here is how it looks
Actual X-PATH

```
//*[@id="tab-form-element-c9ea21e9-9ef1-4867-bd1c-b1fdc9bed6c6"]
```

I tried to use contains in the xpath to trim off that trailing id, and now I don't know how to make the webdriver click on the first or second elements using this path. Is there a better way to handle this kind of scenario??

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains (@id, 'tab-form-element')]")).click();
```

The error returned is as below - I'm thinking the webdriver is not able to identify which element to click 1 or 2.. right?

> unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (352, 525). Other element would receive the click:

============================

Sorry for the delay, here is a snippet of the html for one of the button I need to click inside an iframe. Like this one- there can be at times 2 buttons or 4 buttons - I need to identify and click on each button.

Hope I'm making this clear, I'm new to automation and trying hard to standup with you guys. :)

Sign

```
</div>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Required - <span class="label-text">Sign Here</span></span>
```

Comment: That error indicates that you are trying to click an element that is covered by another element. The covering element is indicated in the error message but you didn't post the whole thing. Please post a link to an example page and we can help or you will need to post the relevant HTML.

Comment: My guess is that your selector is picking up a LOT of elements on the page, the first of which is the one you are trying to click. You will need to find another way to locate the element.

Comment: please post the relevant HTML so that we can find other ways to identify the required elemnt

Comment: if you manually inspect elements, than how many suggestion you found?